# Java / Creating hi/low game using multiple methods, stuck at returning no. of guesses

Tags: java

I'm creating a high/low guessing game as part of a study assignment, and the part im stuck at is getting the amount of guesses returned to the main method. We have specifically been told that the main method has to print the number of guesses, while the method "playGame" actually does the playing.

There's more to the code, a method called giveReponse that checks if the number is correct or too high/low, but it works as intended. I get "Cannot find symbol" when trying to print how many guesses it took to complete the game.
If it wasn't so important to print it in the main method I'd print the amount in the method playGame, but thats a no-go. What am I doing wrong?
The code looks like this:

```
public class HiLo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Welcome to classic guessing game of high/low!");

       String difficulty = scan.next();

          if (difficulty.equals("easy")) {               
             playGame(10);
          } else if (difficulty.equals("medium")) {
             playGame(100);
          } else if (difficulty.equals("hard")) {
             playGame(1000);
          } 

          System.out.println("You won in" + guesses + "attempts.");
   }//EndsMain

       public static int playGame(int maxNumber) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
            int rannr = (int)(Math.random() * maxNumber) +1; 
            int answer = rannr;
            int guess = 0;
            int guesses = 0;

            System.out.println("Game is starting...");

            do {
            guess = scan.nextInt();      
            guesses ++;                   
            giveResponse(answer, guess); 

               if (answer == guess) {
                 break;
               }     
            } while (answer != guess);

       return guesses;
   } //Ends playGame
```

Comment: You're making the classic student/noob mistake: Putting everything in a main class.  Encapsulate all of it in a class; let your main instantiate it and call its methods.  Java's an object-oriented language.  Start thinking about problems in terms of interacting objects.

Comment: Use the return value of method guesses - it should be the value you need to output. You know how to do that - see scan.nextInt().

Comment: Think about the _scope_ of guesses

Comment: Well I am three weeks into programming, and we haven't gotten to multiple classes yet.. In fact, the course I'm taking at the moment won't get into that, this is the final assignment... @duffymo

Comment: We're talking about one class.  You should be able to deal with that.  Three weeks and you haven't written a class?  Silly.  Get your money back.

Comment: @fdsa Please don't make exceus think of a global static - that's not what Teacher would like to see!

Comment: The difficulty of the game is not controlled by just the range of values.  You should also restrict the number of guesses allowed.  You can always get this right using a bisection strategy if you're given enough guesses.  It's certain to get the right answer for the range of (1,100) with ten guesses; it's a challenge if you allow five or less.

Comment: @Iaune I was not intending to provide you with an excuse but rather to help you understand why you were getting that error message

Comment: @duffymo its not part of the assignment to add a some kind of restriction to the amount of guesses, but my plan is to continue working on this small "game" and its a great idea. Thanks!

Comment: I would say that something insightful, novel, and independent would be gratifying for your professor.  In the real world assignments aren't nearly this prescriptive.  How sad that students don't want to think.

Comment: @Duffymo I have no professor,  it's a four week course taken online. :)

Comment: :) it would be totally different if was attending college or if I was a full time student. The course itself sucked, felt no need to be insightful or novel as I could only pass or fail. There's no A, B or C grades.

Comment: No, it's not different.  Thinking for yourself and being creative is a good thing regardless of context.  Sorry, I disagree.

Comment: No arguments there. However in this case I only asked how to solve this specific issue. I am going to try to get this into a small app for android, to put it on my phone. I just didn't feel like writing an essay about everything around the code, since it doesnt belong to the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `playGame(  )` is returning a value but since is not assigned to no variable, those returns are getting lost...
additional to that it looks like the code is not complete:

this statement is not going to let you compile:

```
System.out.println("You won in" + guesses + "attempts.");
```

because **the only `guesses` variable I see in there is scoped in the playGame method**....

do instead something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to classic guessing game of high/low!");
    int guesses = 0;
    String difficulty = scan.next();

    if (difficulty.equals("easy")) {
        guesses = playGame(10);
    } else if (difficulty.equals("medium")) {
        guesses = playGame(100);
    } else if (difficulty.equals("hard")) {
        guesses = playGame(1000);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Xoce for a fast reply! This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at:

```
System.out.println("You won in" + guesses + "attempts.");
```

Since the variable `guesses` is not defined in the main method, the compiler doesn't know what you are referencing to with that symbol.

But since `playGame()` returns the number of guesses, I'd recommend something like this:

```
if (difficulty.equals("easy")) {               
         System.out.println("You won in" +playGame(10)+ "attempts.");
      } else if (difficulty.equals("medium")) {
         System.out.println("You won in" +playGame(100)+ "attempts.");
      } else if (difficulty.equals("hard")) {
         System.out.println("You won in" +playGame(1000)+ "attempts.");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that shows how easy it would be to restrict guesses.  Not much extra effort or thought:

```
package games;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * HiLo guessing game
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 4/9/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522303/java-creating-hi-low-game-using-multiple-methods-stuck-at-returning-no-of-gu
 */
public class HiLo {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int maxValue = (args.length > 0) ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : 100;
        int maxGuesses = (args.length > 1) ? Integer.parseInt(args[1]) : 5;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = "Y";
        do {
            play(scanner, maxValue, maxGuesses);
            System.out.println("Play again? [Y/N]: ");
            answer = scanner.next();
            System.out.println(String.format("You answered %s; let's play again!", answer));
        } while ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer));
    }

    private static void play(Scanner scanner, int maxValue, int maxGuesses) {
        int value = new Random().nextInt(maxValue) + 1;
        int numGuesses = 0;
        boolean match = false;
        do {
            System.out.println(String.format("Guess a value between 1 and %d: ", maxValue));
            int guess = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
            if (guess < value) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Too low; guess again. (%d guesses left)", (maxGuesses-numGuesses-1)));
            } else if (guess > value) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Too high; guess again (%d guesses left)", (maxGuesses-numGuesses-1)));
            } else {
                match = true;
                System.out.println(String.format("You got it right in %d guesses! ", numGuesses+1));
                break;
            }
        } while (!match && ++numGuesses < maxGuesses);
        if (!match) {
            System.out.println(String.format("The correct answer was %d; you're only allowed %d guesses.  Better luck next time!", value, maxGuesses));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool stuff! I'm only four weeks into programming, and the course I took didn't go into stuff like parse and args etc yet, it's not considered basic by the school that offer the course.. But huge thanks! As I learn more this will be helpful :)